# In Modern Warfare II, Which killstreak combination stacks the easiest/fastest?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Now this question may seem obvious, duh -- killstreaks that come one after another like UAV/Counter-UAV/Predator Missile -- but I am talking about sets of killstreaks that unlock each other while you lay around hiding somewhere - or at least work well enough on their own so you need to only get 1 or 2 kills to get the next killstreak. Right now I have Harrier Strike/Pavelow/AC-130 or Chopper Gunner (depending on map). Once I get my harrier I call it in, then go off somewhere safe for my Pavelow to be ready (I can sometimes get my Pavelow from the Harrier's strike, not even needing to wait for the 3rd harrier to start hovering).

Any other Killstreak combos that work well together?

Answer (score 3):

Predator
Harrier
Pavelow

Ok, this is a noobish kind of annoying strategy, but meh.

Use claymores and scavenger (it will make it **REALLY** easy to get a 5 killstreak for your predator). Once you get that, well, the harrier comes as a free gift. In TDM you usually find 2 guys together ready to get killed by the predator missile.

Once the harrier is out you need 2 kills to get the pavelow, so piece of cake too.

The reasons I prefer these killstreaks are these:

1. Predator is a really easy kill
2. Harriers are way more powerful than the attack helis. Attack helis just suck, if you they get you 2 kills you got extremely lucky. Yeah, they last more, but they suck so much people just ignore them.
3. Pavelow is so easy to get once the harrier is out, it's really powerful and it has one flare, so it takes 2 missiles to bring it down.

I personally use these:

TDM

- Predator
- Harrier
- AC130 (People tend to not bring it down since it has 2 flares)

FFA

- Predator
- Harrier
- Chopper Gunner (It's closer to the ground and can fire continuously, so it's a really good option. It does have only one flare, but in FFA people don't shoot down air support as much)

And yeah, I do not use claymores / scavenger combo anymore. It's noobish. ---

Comment: I know plenty of people that have success with the predator, but I usually get no kills and often die in the laptop. I have a much better time with the Precision Airstrike. It's quicker to launch, and hits a wider area. Just a suggestion. Also, it's worth noting that Danger Close Pro makes all of the killstreaks stronger. You can use One Man Army to switch to a class with Danger Close Pro before calling in your killstreaks. This will make the explosions stronger, and also the aircraft guns.

Answer (score 0):

I've never been exceptionally good at MW2 so I've always set up my killstreaks so that I have a reasonable chance of getting them all every time I'm alive.  It's much more fun when you have a few killstreaks to use during a key part of the match or to get a group of enemies out of a highly defensible position.

I generally use Predator/Attack Helicopter(or Harrier)/Pavelow

These lead fairly well between each other and there's a decent chance one could lay low after getting the predator and get the next two killstreaks.

Comment: Attack heli sucks dude. Do not use it, it won't get you kills.

Comment: I've had some success with it on some of the more wide-open maps.  It's susceptible to RPGs/grenade launchers/etc... but so is the Harrier and I have better luck with the longer loiter time than the maybe 1 kill I would get from the Harrier bombing run.

Do you have any tips on maximizing the efficacy of the Harrier bombing run?  I would love to get better at them.